# SQL Server Integration Service Literal Values

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have this doubt, in SSIS I need to take the values from table A to table B. The thing is, some of the columns of B do not belong to A, and at the end, when I am doing the mapping I got something like this:

**(Inside the Data Flow Task:
OLE DB Source -> Conditional Split -> Data Conversion -> OLE DB Destination
)**

column1   column1

`<`ignore>  column2

`<`ignore>  column3

column4   column4

The values for column2 and column3 are literal, like "a", "b". But in the data flow I have not seen how to indicate this two values to table B.

Is it possible to do it without using a script task to update the table after inserting the values?

I hope I have explained everything clearly.

Comment: What are you trying to do with those two columns if they don't have matching columns in your destination?

Comment: Hi Andrew, right now I am translating an Access projecto into SSIS. This is the first time that I use this tool. And this two columns are needed later to match some information that I got form table A and the values that I need to insert with other tables.

Comment: THen I think you'll need to add them to your destination table. Or, if each column contains a single value for the whole table, you could store them in variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two choices. The best way is to add a Derived Column task to your Data Flow - probably right before the OLEDB Destination. In there, create the literal columns. The Expressions should be pretty simple, like "abcd" or 1234. No need for complicated calculations, right?

The other (less good, but perfectly fine) way is to modify the query in the OLEDB Source to add additional columns. Set the Data Access mode to SQL Query and write something like this:

```
Select column1, column4, 'abcd' as column2, 1234 as column3 From sourcetable
```